# VS Code API | Context menu inside function

Tags: visual-studio-code, contextmenu, abstract-syntax-tree, vscode-extensions

I'm currently building an extension for VS Code.
I want my editor's context menu for a command to be displayed only if current file has `.c` extension and current line (pointed by cursor) is inside a function. The first thing is trivial, here is my code:

```
"editor/context": [
    {
        "command": "extension.myCommand",
        "when": "editorLangId == c",
        "group": "MyGroup@1"
    }
]
```

However, I don't know how to check whether current line is a part of a function body. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can try to use [babel-parser](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-parser) to parse and identify if the cursor inside a function. You can use [`setContext`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/master/api/extension-guides/command.md#using-a-custom-when-clause-context) to declare a global context to use in the `when` clause.